# Is it ok to use children method in abstract class? pep8 says instance has no member

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, abstract-class, pep8

I use pep8 in visual studio code and I just tried to write some abstract classes.

The problem is I get the error `[pylint] E1101:Instance of 'MyAbstract' has no 'child_method' member` because pep8 does not realise that the method is well defined, but in the child classes.

To illustrate my problem here is a code snippet that is reducted to the minimum for clarity:

```
class MyAbstract:

    def some_method(self):
        newinfo = self.child_method()
        # use newinfo 

class MyChild(MyAbstract):

    def child_method(self):
        # Do something in a way

class OtherChild(MyAbstract):

    def child_method(self):
        # Do the same thing in a different way
```

**So my questions are:**

- Is it ok to write classes like this?
- How would you solve the error? (disable error, use another pattern, ...)

**Clarification**

The MyAbstract class shouldn't be instanciated, and the child classes will inherit the `some_method`. The idea is to use it on child class instances.

Comment: you should define the method on the abstract class; either have it be an empty method using `pass` if you don't intend to require the child to override it, or have it throw an error if you do

Comment: thank you for thjis suggestion, will be easier to do than to add rule deactivations everywhere!

Answer (score 5):

If you want `MyAbstract` to be an abstract class with abstract method `child_method`, Python has a way of expressing that in the [`abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) module:

```
import abc

class MyAbstract(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def child_method(self):
        pass

    def some_method(self):
        newinfo = self.child_method()
        do_whatever_with(newinfo)
```

Your linter will no longer complain about the nonexistent method, and as a bonus, Python will detect attempts to instantiate a class with unimplemented abstract methods.

Comment: Indeed, I just read the answer that you indicated and it indirectly solves my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @RomainVincent: Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.